# Zip my folder but do not overwrite existing one in C#

Tags: c#, directory, overwrite, fastzip

I am using third party FastZip to zip my folder, when i zip new folder with already existing file let say abc.zip, Fast Zip overwite this old abc.zip, delete old files and zip only new files.

Any one knows the solution.

EDIT-> I managed to do that by myself, Here is a solution if some one need.

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;

string zipfilename = "abc.zip"; // Your required zip file
string fdrname = "abc";

if (!File.Exists(zipfilename)) // If file zip does not exists
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fdrname); // Create folder with same name
    FastZip fz = new FastZip();         // using FastZip dll
    fz.CreateZip(zipfilename, fdrname, true, null); // create zip file (ofcourse its empty)
}
if (Directory.Exists(fdrname)) // delete folder which you have created (optional)
    Directory.Delete(fdrname);

    try
    {
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipfilename); // by Using ZipFile dll
        zip.BeginUpdate();
        zip.Add(pathtofile); // add file path which you want to zip in abc.zip
        zip.CommitUpdate();
        zip.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always manually test for file existence before zipping:

```
if (!File.Exists(filename))
    fastZip.CreateZip(filename, @"C:\SourceDirectory", recurse, filter);
else
    //exception or message
```

Comment: This is what i am doing already but what if (File.Exists(filename))

Comment: That is up to you. What do you want happening?